# Move all messages from deadletter queue back into main queue of subscription

Tags: azure, message-queue, azureservicebus

My service consumes messages from an Azure Service Bus subscription. A dependency of my service was down for a while, which caused a lot of messages to end up in the deadletter queue (DLQ). Now that the service is back up, I want to reprocess all messages from the DLQ. How can I move/resubmit all messages from the DLQ back in to the main queue.

Restrictions:

- It's thousands of messages, so manually handling them isn't feasible.
- The topic has about ten subscriptions. I don't want to resubmit the messages to the topic, because then all subscriptions would receive the messages, leading to double-processing.
- I don't want to run the service against the DLQ directly, because some messages are broken and cause permanent errors, i.e. they would end up in the DLQ again, which would lead to an infinite loop. Moreover, the broken messages are put back at the *front* of the queue, effectively starving healthy messages that come after the broken ones.

Answer (score 4):

I realize this is a while after the original post but if anyone else stumbles on this problem, there is a fairly handy solution baked into the [Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) (which I have found to be incredibly handy with ASB development).

After connecting to your Service Bus and finding the needed namespace, find the desired `topic` and `subscription` with the deadletters in it. From there `Right Click` and `Receive Deadletter Queue Messages` and hit OK.

From there, highlight which you would like to send back to the main queue and hit `Resubmit Selected Messages in Batch Mode`.

Comment: This is not going to work unfortunately, as you can only send them back to the topic and not to a specific subscription, resulting in all the subscriptions receiving the same messages again

See Lance's answer below

Comment: It's been over 2 years so the details on my usage may be fuzzy, but I believe using `topic filters` as Lance's answer suggests simply filters the messages to the right subscriptions, and would work in combination with my answer on how to resubmit the messages.

Answer (score 3):

The only option to replay DLQ messages is to receive them from DLQ, create new message with same content and send it again to the topic. They will end up at the end of subscription queue.

You can't send messages directly to the subscription. There is a trick to add a metadata property to the message, and then adjust all except one subscription to filter out such messages. It's up to you to decide if it's going to help in your scenario.

As for tooling, we always did that with custom code, because we always needed some extra work to be done, like logging each replayed message for further analysis.

Comment: Is there a good reason why messages can't be moved back to the main queue per design? I'd expect that use case to be fairly common.

Comment: @ThS Good question, but I've never seen any official motivation for that. I guess it's just "by design".

Comment: My assumption is that you don't want to retry indefinitely messages. If you try to call a service that is unavailable you want to wait for this service to be available again before retrying.  So you can increase the `max delivery count` if you need more retries or implement a circuit breaker ?

Comment: In practice, when the service is back running, I want to _manually_ press a button that moves all messages from the DLQ back to the main queue. Doing this manually prevents infinite retries. Increasing `max delivery count` would not work, because if the service it down for a long time, messages still end up in the DLQ.

Answer (score 3):

Thomas, you probably already found your answer since this is quite awhile ago. think of DLQ (or any existing queue that you have) as just another collection variable like in a PC app, but residing on the cloud. just like a PC-app or in-memory collection variable from your tool-kit, you have many ways of utilising it. off course there are limitations and differences between these 2 types of collection variables, but that's how you design your solution as though the DLQ is just another collection variable by knowing those limitations and differences.

For some queuing implementations, one of the solutions would be to have another instance of the same app pointing to the DLQ, but with a fairly long visibility timeout (e.g. 6 or 12 or even 24 hours depending on your SLA), since you don't want to repeat them too often. However, this is not applicable to Azure service bus, as it limits the visibility timeout to at most 5 minutes.

if the DLQ contains broken un-recoverable jobs, you should fix the app to delete them based on the error messages when the unknown exception occurred. once the fix is deployed, such broken un-recoverable jobs would have been removed by your app and never get sent to the DLQ in the first place. and those already in the DLQ will be removed by the fixed app.

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that you cannot directly move messages back to the main queue of a subscription. This is by design with how Microsoft implemented their topics and subscriptions.

**Option #1**
There is the option to use Azure Service Bus topic filters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters and define/tag your messages in a manner that would only allow them to be received on the targeted subscription.

**Option #2**
The other option would be to change your current implementation. You would set up "delivery queues" (regular service bus queues) and configure each corresponding subscription to auto forward its messages to these delivery queues. Your message processing logic would then listen on these "delivery queues" vs the subscription. Any failures would then result in DLQ messages on these associated "delivery queues" which could then be handled outside of the topic/subscriptions.